# Scheme: using a procedure within a procedure or how to count the number of occurrence of each element

Tags: scheme, procedure

```
(require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme:1:2/simply-scheme))

(define (ball-val value)
   (let ((color value))
       (cond ((equal? 'R color) 5)
             ((equal? 'W color) 2)
             ((equal? 'B color) 2)
             ((equal? 'G color) 1))))

(define (count-balls color bucket)
    (count (keep (lambda (c) (equal? color c)) bucket)))
```

The two procedures give the value of each colored ball and counts the number of balls in a bucket given a specific color.

Another procedure called color-counts needs to be written to output a sentence of number of each colored ball in a bucket, given that the only parameter is a bucket of balls.

> Write a procedure `color-counts` that takes a bucket as its argument and returns a sentence containing the number of reds, the number of green, the number of blues, and the number of whites in the bucket.
>
> ex:
>
> ```
>   (color-counts '(R B G R R R B W R W))
>     '(5 1 2 2)
>
>   (color-counts '(W R R R R G B B G W))
>     '(4 2 2 2)
> ```

Is it possible to call `count-balls` in a `color-count` and just call `count-balls` for each color in `color-count`? or is that not possible?

I tried:

```
(define (color-counts bucket) 
  (count-balls 'R bucket count-balls 'W bucket count-balls 'B bucket count-balls 'G bucket))
```

All I get is:

```
#<procedure ...>
```

Comment: Can we have some code?

Comment: Of course you can call `count-balls` inside `color-counts`. Just like you call `count` and `keep` inside `count-balls`. You can call any procedure inside any other procedure.

Comment: When I call count-balls in color-count? All I get is #<procedure>

Comment: You must not be calling it, you're just returning it.

Comment: Your code shouldn't have returned `#<procedure>`. It should have reported an error that you're calling `count-balls` with the wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any procedure you like from any other procedure.

You're calling `count-balls` incorrectly. It only takes 2 arguments, but you're calling it with 11 arguments. You need to write separate calls for each color, not put them all in one call. And you need to wrap that in a call to `list` to create a list of all the results.

```
(define (color-count bucket)
  (list (count-balls 'R bucket)
        (count-balls 'G bucket)
        (count-balls 'B bucket)
        (count-balls 'W bucket)))
```

You can also use the `map` function to remove all the repeated code:

```
(define (color-count bucket)
  (map (lambda (color) (count-balls color bucket))
       '(R G B W)))
```

`map` calls the procedure repeatedly with each element of the list `(R G B W)` as its argument, and returns a list of all the results.

Comment: can you explain to me what map does to have a better understanding of what the code is doing? I am assuming that it maps R G B W with the key in count-ball procedure

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer

Comment: how would I add all the values together to get the total number of ball? would I put the operator + in between each one

Comment: @Rachel You can replace `list` with `+` and instead of a list of results you get the sum.

Comment: @Rachel You can also use `(apply + (color-count bucket))` to calculate the sum of the list returned.